# Refactoring repeated if statement within if else block

Tags: javascript

I have this if blocks where i have to test within on the same thing in both blocks :

```
   if (download !== 'true') {
     if(index == undefined){
       res.json(req.doc);
     }else{
       res.json(index)
     }
   } else {
     if(index == undefined){
       exports.download(res, req.doc);
     }else{
       res.json(index)
     }
   }
```

Is there a way to refactor it in a way in which i wouldn't repeat the same thing ?

Comment: you check against a string. is it right?

Comment: Why is the value of download a string? Why are you using `==` and not `===` on index?

Comment: it's actually a string, i just named it index of an object given which is the name of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you do the same thing in both branches when `index == undefined` is false, just do that test first and invert it:

```
if (index != undefined) {
  res.json(index);
} else if (download !== 'true') {
  res.json(req.doc);
} else {
  exports.download(res, req.doc);
}
```

---

Side notes:

- `== undefined` and `!= undefined` will treat `undefined` and `null` the same way. If you don't want your conditions to treat `null` like `undefined`, use `===` and `!==`.
- It's slightly odd that `download` is a *string*, although of course that does happen sometimes. **If** `download` is actually a boolean, then `!== 'true'` will always be true (because no boolean is ever strictly equal to a string). **If** it's a boolean, use `if (download)` or `if (!download)` rather than `=== true` or `!== true`. If it *is* a string, beware of whitespace at the beginning or end and capitalization (`' true' !== 'true'` is `true` because of the space; `'True' !== 'true'` is `true` because of the capital `T`). FWIW.

Comment: oh it worked for me and thank you for the detailed explanation